# Скрипт для выполнение http запросов по url из google sheets

Tags: php, google-spreadsheet

Есть 100000 строк готовых url запросов в google sheets (A1:A100000), нужно скриптом выполнить их все. Отправить get запрос по идее. Не силен в программировании. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Познакомьтесь с методом [UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object)). Будьте готовы к различным [квотам](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas?hl=en) со стороны Google.